# If 7th day and 14th day, Send-MailMessage

Tags: powershell, email, getdate

Using the code below I'm able to email a specific person when a contractor's AD account is within two weeks of expiring. My issue is the code will trigger daily via Task Scheduler and send the email every day. Are we able to use something like an if statement to logically act on specific timing conditions? Perhaps something like

*if* AccountExpirationDate = getdate.adddays(-14) send-mailmessage
 *if* AccountExpirationDate = getdate.adddays(-7) send-mailmessage

If not, what would be the best way to get this done?

```
# List every active account with a "SACRequest Account" desctription that will expire in 14 days and inlcude the name and email address of the original account requester (extensionAttribute1,extensionAttribute2)
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Today = Get-Date
$Expires = $Today.AddDays(14) 
$reportObject = @()
$userList = Get-ADUser -Filter {Description -like "SACRequest Account" -and Enabled -eq $True} -Properties displayname, accountExpires, description, passwordexpired,"msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed",enabled,AccountExpirationDate,LastLogonDate,logoncount,passwordlastset, badlogoncount,lastbadpasswordattempt,extensionAttribute1,extensionAttribute2,department |
    select displayname, accountExpires, description, passwordexpired,"msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed",enabled,AccountExpirationDate,LastLogonDate,logoncount,passwordlastset, badlogoncount,lastbadpasswordattempt,extensionAttribute1,extensionAttribute2,department |
    Where-Object {$_.accountExpires -ne $NeverExpires  -and [datetime]::FromFileTime([int64]::Parse($_.accountExpires)) -ne $Expires}
    Sort-Object msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed -Descending
$obj = New-Object PSObject
foreach ($user in $userList) {
    # SPLAT
    $obj = New-Object PSObject
    $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Name($user.displayname)
    $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Description($user.description)
    $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty 'Password Expired'($user.Passwordexpired)
    $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty 'Account is Enabled'($user.Enabled)
    $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty 'AccountExpirationDate'($user.AccountExpirationDate.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy'))
    $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty 'LastLogonDate'($user.LastLogonDate.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy'))
    $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty 'Password Last Set'($user.PasswordLastSet)   
    $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty 'Failed Logon Attempt'($user.lastbadpasswordattempt) 
    $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty 'TotalLogonCount'($user.logoncount)
    $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty 'Total Failed Logons'($user.badlogoncount)
    $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty 'SACSubmitter'($user.extensionAttribute1)
    $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty 'SACSubmitterEmail'($user.extensionAttribute2)
    $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty 'Department'($user.department)
    #$obj | Add-Member NoteProperty 'Password Expiration Date'($outputexp.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy'))
    $reportObject += $obj
}
# Export CSV containing all SACR accounts expiring soon.
$reportObject | Export-Csv -Path \\intranet\c$\IT\SystemAccessControlRequestForm\SACRAccountsExpiringSoon.csv -NoTypeInformation
# Send email notification to system administrators.
Send-MailMessage -From ncaban@organization.org -To ncaban@organization.org -Subject "New System Access Control Request Export" -body "New System Access Control Request Export can be found here file://///intranet/c$/IT/SystemAccessRequestForm/"  -SmtpServer mail.organization.org
# Send email notification to original submitter
$from    =  "Your Friends in IT <systems@organization.org>"
$subject =  "Your contractors's login account will expire soon!"      
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "\\intranet\c$\IT\SystemAccessControlRequestForm\SACRAccountsExpiringSoon.csv"
foreach ($user in $csv) {
    $Name = $user.name
    $to = $user.SACSubmitterEmail
    $hello = $user.SACSubmitter
    #$AccountExpirationDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
    $AccountExpirationDate = $user.AccountExpirationDate # -as [DateTime]
    $TotalLogonCount = $user.TotalLogonCount
    $LastLogonDate = $user.LastLogonDate
    $body =  "Hello $hello,<br><br>"
    $body +=  "The login account you requested for <b>$Name</b> is set to expire on <b> $AccountExpirationDate</b>.<br><br>"
    $body +=  "$name logged onto our systems a total of <b>$TotalLogonCount</b> times with the last successful log in posted on <b> $LastLogonDate</b>.<br><br>"
    $body +=  "<a href='http://intranet/Intranet/forms/viewform.cfm?formid=154'>If this account needs to remain active please submit a new System Access Control Request by clicking here.</a><br><br>"
    $body +=  "Kind Regards,<br>"
    $body +=  "Your friends in IT"
    $mail = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Mailmessage $from, $to, $subject, $body
    $mail.IsBodyHTML=$true
    $server = "mail.organization.org"
    $port   = 25
    $Smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SMTPClient $server,$port
    $Smtp.Credentials = [system.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
    $smtp.Send($mail)
}
```

Comment: Why not schedule the task on weekly basis?

Comment: Hypothetically, if it's scheduled the day after an account would be flagged it would have the original requester losing six days to act on the account. What I want to ensure is something like "These are the accounts expiring exactly 14 days from today - send the email". Then again at 7 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely do that with some like this:

```
$Today = Get-Date -Format 'MM-dd-yyy'
foreach ($user in $csv) {
  if (([datetime]$user.AccountExpirationDate).AddDays(-14) -eq $Today) {
    #send the report
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Scott this works perfectly. I added it to my existing ps and aftering tinkering with some test account expiration dates I got the expected result each time. Thanks!

Comment: @nominus - I was think about it and I think you should have a 1 day warning as well.  because you know how people are!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [vonPryz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503046/vonpryz) that you should schedule this weekly.

About your script, I think it can do with a litte tidying up. For one thing, your variable `$NeverExpires` is never defined, where you comment `# SPLAT` is not splatting at all, plus you create a CSV file from an array of objects and later import that CSV file again, while you still have the `$reportObject`.

Maybe something like below would be more maintainable:

```
# List every active account with a "SACRequest Account" desctription that will expire within 14 days
# and inlcude the name and email address of the original account requester (extensionAttribute1,extensionAttribute2)
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Today      = Get-Date
$Expires    = $Today.AddDays(14) 
$properties = 'DisplayName', 'accountExpires', 'AccountExpirationDate', 'Description', 'PasswordExpired', 'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed',
              'Enabled', 'LastLogonDate', 'logonCount', 'passwordlastset', 'BadLogonCount', 'LastBadPasswordAttempt', 
              'extensionAttribute1', 'extensionAttribute2', 'Department'
$filter     = "Description -like '*SACRequest Account*' -and Enabled -eq 'True' -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq 'False' -and PasswordNotRequired -eq 'False'"

$userList   = Get-ADUser -Filter $filter -Properties $properties | 
              Where-Object {$_.accountExpires -ne 0 -and $_.accountExpires -ne 9223372036854775807 -and $_.AccountExpirationDate -ge $Expires} |
              Sort-Object -Poperty 'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed' -Descending

$reportObject = foreach ($user in $userList) {
    $pwExpiresAt = [datetime]::FromFileTime($user."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'Name'                     = $user.DisplayName
        'Description'              = $user.Description
        'Password Expired'         = $user.PasswordExpired
        'Password Expiration Date' = $pwExpiresAt.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')
        'Account is Enabled'       = $user.Enabled
        'AccountExpirationDate'    = $user.AccountExpirationDate.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')
        'LastLogonDate'            = $user.LastLogonDate.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')
        'Password Last Set'        = $user.PasswordLastSet
        'Failed Logon Attempt'     = $user.LastBadPasswordAttempt
        'TotalLogonCount'          = $user.logonCount
        'Total Failed Logons'      = $user.BadLogonCount
        'SACSubmitter'             = $user.extensionAttribute1
        'SACSubmitterEmail'        = $user.extensionAttribute2
        'Department'               = $user.Department
    }
}

# Export CSV containing all SACR accounts expiring soon.
$reportObject | Export-Csv -Path '\\intranet\c$\IT\SystemAccessControlRequestForm\SACRAccountsExpiringSoon.csv' -NoTypeInformation

# Send email notification to system administrators.
# splat
$mailParams = @{
     'From'       = 'ncaban@organization.org'
     'To'         = 'ncaban@organization.org'
     'Subject'    = 'New System Access Control Request Export'
     'Body'       = "New System Access Control Request Export can be found here file://///intranet/c$/IT/SystemAccessRequestForm/"
     'SmtpServer' = 'mail.organization.org'
}
Send-MailMessage @mailParams

# Send email notification to original submitter
# Any reason why you do not use Send-MailMessage here?
$from    =  "Your Friends in IT <systems@organization.org>"
$subject =  "Your contractors's login account will expire soon!"      
$reportObject | ForEach-Object {
    $name  = $_.Name
    $to    = $_.SACSubmitterEmail
    $hello = $_.SACSubmitter
    $AccountExpirationDate = $_.AccountExpirationDate
    $TotalLogonCount = $_.TotalLogonCount
    $LastLogonDate = $_.LastLogonDate
    # a Here-String is used for the HTML body
    $body =  @"
Hello $hello,<br><br>
The login account you requested for <b>$name</b> is set to expire on <b>$AccountExpirationDate</b>.<br><br>
$name logged onto our systems a total of <b>$TotalLogonCount</b> times with the last successful log in posted on <b>$LastLogonDate</b>.<br><br>
<a href='http://intranet/Intranet/forms/viewform.cfm?formid=154'><br><br>
If this account needs to remain active please submit a new System Access Control Request by clicking here.</a><br><br>
Kind Regards,<br>Your friends in IT
"@
    $mail   = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Mailmessage $from, $to, $subject, $body
    $mail.IsBodyHTML = $true
    $server = "mail.organization.org"
    $port   = 25
    $Smtp   = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SMTPClient $server, $port
    $Smtp.Credentials = [system.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
    $Smtp.Send($mail)
}
```

Comment: This looks so much better than what I cobbled together, thanks! I'm having an issue with the filter though. It works if I modify it down to
$filter     = "Description -like 'SACRequest Account'"
Anything more than that and I get the following:
Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: 'Description -like 'SACRequest Account' -and Enabled -eq True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq False' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '57'.
At line:12 char:15
+ $userList   = Get-ADUser -Filter $filter -Properties $properties |

Comment: @Theothe problem with the weekly run is that what he wants is 7 or 14 day notice.  If you run it ever 7 days you might only get notices on 8 and 1 days remaining.  Running it daily and checking that the time until expiration is either 7 or 14 days away is the only way to do this that I can think of.  Also, great job on the code cleanup!

Comment: @nominus Filter is always a pain when more properties are involved.. I have updated the quoting there. Can you try?

Comment: @ScottHeath You have a point there. If he wants the reminders exactly 14 and 7 days ahead, then the schedule should be daily.